# Can the SVG export export edges?

Tags: rendering, freestyle, svg

I would like to export the visible edges of a shape into SVG lines.

At the moment, I am only able to export lines that are made visible by lighting:

[image]

But I would like to export all the edges (for example the ones on top of the head here which were not rendered).

I accept answers for both 2.79 and 2.8+ versions of Blender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add-on [**Viewport to SVG**](https://blenderartists.org/t/svg-output-script/566412) can do this ... and many other things.
*Tested with Blender 2.92 (2.93 will need attention ...)*

[image]

[image]

Edit: Any add-on contains location info ... 3D View Editor > Sidepanel <kbd>N</kbd> > SVG tab

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your screenshot truncates the top of the window, what tab do I find "Export SVG" after installing it? Can you share a screenshot of a result you obtained?

Comment: Curves are generated (as name state) from point of view and you can result with many variations just check it out ... like export only selected faces or export facing only (like here) so faces not visible from view are not included ...

Comment: Awesome thanks!