# How to render to flat white with black borders

Tags: rendering, texturing, lighting, texture-painting

I'm pretty new in blender and I'm try to drawing some objects to get a vector-pencildraw representation style, like an instructory manual:

[image]

I could create the object but I can't render it as I need, I can paint it in white plain but I can't remove the shadows of the light, neither paint in plain black the lines of the borders.

I change the background to Viewport in white but also no effect over the background.

(Silly demo with a cube, is not my figure)

[image]

and my render:

[image]

UPDATE:

After a bit work and search I could do this:

[image]

but I don't know why I see it gray even when I selected plain white 000

Sorry for the noob question, thanks in advance for any help and/or comment

Comment: One thing can be - default blender material is not pure white but 0.800 ... second - by default Color Management is set to Filmic, change it to Standard ... you can also export [Viewport to SVG](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/215275/2214) with addon (for curvy shapes enable Bezier Overlay).

Comment: I know the main point has been answered for you.. but you haven't mentioned that you're using Freestyle, or Line Art, for your black-line. .. are you not using either of those?

Comment: Hi @RobinBetts no problem I'll glad to help others for further reference or improve my own work. I did it following a tutorial for blueprints, make a stroke with lineart over my collection (I've a collection as group of little items and the collection is the object itself). The "material" of my stroke is black, the stroke with a modifier Line Art. I don't know what I'm talking about to be honest, just followed the tutorial and get a result. The josh answer by image is better than mine because has two types of strokes, but I don't know how to do it and I don't want disturb

Comment: @RobinBetts this is the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQqUQ5JOZjY&ab_channel=SouthernShotty

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Thanks for your reply, and link. Southern Shotty is a nice reliable source :) .  Josh has covered your case, but I just added a couple of notes that would have been in my answer, in case they're useful to you, or to the archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get pure white and black renders in Eevee, you can delete any light source (even world), set the color management to Standard with none as look, use a simple emission shader for 1.0 white and a copy of the same material deleting the emission node for black.

In my example there is a plane whith the same white material as background.

[image]

Comment: This is not limited to _Eevee_, you can do the same in _Cycles_ as well. However, your scene looks like it is just a default cube and nothing else. But in my Blender when I delete the world shader the background is black not white, in both _Eevee_ and _Cycles_. So maybe for beginners it might be interesting what you did to get a white background.

Comment: I updated my answer, there's no need to use Cycles for this kind of renders.

Comment: No need, but to a beginner the first sentence might sound as if this was a specific _Eevee_ method and thus not seem suitable to someone who wants to use _Cycles_ in particular for whatever reason. The OP does not specify a render engine either. Anyway, this was just an additional information for beginners to your answer. The different colored background will be more confusing to newbies, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try this in a few hours when I back home.

Answer (score 1):

These are just a couple of supplementary notes; not intended to intrude on [Josh's rightfully accepted answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/289538/35559) to your actual question.

If you needed the flexibility, or were producing for a client who might suddenly change their mind :) then you can render a Line-Art only layer, by [holding out](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/284463/35559) all the geometry the Line-Art is founded on.

If you set the Film to 'Transparent' in the Render tab, you can defer decisions on line and background color to the compositor. The result will depend only on the Alpha of the rendered layer, there's no concern with the light-response of the objects or the strokes:

[image]

It's maybe also worth noting that a Line-Art Grease-Pencil stroke is  first-class 3D geometry. In perspective, through a wide-enough angle lens, the variation in thickness with distance becomes noticeable:

[image]

This can be fixed by setting the Stroke Thickness to 'Screen Space' in the 'Strokes' panel in the GP Layer's Data tab.

[image]

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot!!!! this will help me a lot!!

Comment: I maybe broke it because now I cant back to the original one neither what you recommend, i get this: https://imgur.com/a/3bElF8B

Comment: I think you'll have to share that one, on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I finally did it! Forget it, my mistake. That's perfect because I'm working with PSD, so now I only have lines, is that what I really need, you solve my XY problem. This should be the accepted answer but I admit I asked for different thing.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Great! No problem at all. Josh answered the question you actually asked.